# draw 3D yield surfaces with matplotlib

Tags: python, 3d, numpy, matplotlib

I was wondering how to draw 3D yield surfaces as shown on this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_yield_criterion. I have been trying to draw the von Mises yield surface as a start but with no success at all. I think I do not know how to start at all. If someone could show me an example code for example for von Mises then I could use that to plot some other yield surfaces like the Cam Clay and Modified Cam Clay.

Initially I thought I could do something like this but it does not work:

```
for i in range(0, MAXSTEP):
    stressx = stressx + STEPSIZE
    stressy = -STEPSIZE
    for j in range(0, MAXSTEP):
        stressy = stressy + STEPSIZE
        stressz = -STEPSIZE
        for k in range(0, MAXSTEP):
            stressz = stressz + STEPSIZE
            tI1 = calcI1(stressx, stressy, stressz)
            tJ2 = calcJ2(stressx, stressy, stressz)
            tyieldf = calcF(tI1, ycon)
            tsqrtJ2 = np.sqrt(tJ2)
            tdiff = abs(tsqrtJ2 - tyieldf)
            if  tdiff < TOL:
                sigx[count] = stressx
                sigy[count] = stressy
                sigz[count] = stressy
                I1[count] = tI1
                sqrtJ2[count] = tsqrtJ2
                diff[count] = tdiff
                count = count + 1

X = np.outer(sigx[0:count], sigx[0:count])
Y = np.outer(sigy[0:count], sigy[0:count])
Z = np.outer(sigz[0:count], sigz[0:count])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
main()
```

I think I do not know how to generate the data. I have the equations but do not know how to use them to generate data required for surface plot. I think I need to generate a XY mesh and then solve it for Z but I haven't tried that method yet.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried, perhaps a code snippet that doesn't work?

Comment: Is the problem with the generation of the yield surface or the plotting of it?

Comment: I think my problem is with the generation of the data. I have the equations but do not know how to use them to generate data required for surface plot. I think I need to generate a XY mesh and then solve the yield equation for Z but I haven't tried that method yet. Even if I were able to do the above I am not sure how to set up the Z array for surface plot. I would have attached my program but seems like it is too long for this comment section.